# HP Pro Tablet Active Pen on HP Probook

Tags: stylus

my question is, if there are any advanced solutions for Pen use without wacom

I've tried enable the active pen on the Pro book (Ubuntu 18.4) but it didn't work and i have no clue why. After hours of google i don't know what to do. The Pen worked once with a HP Pavilion x2.

Are there any ideas what i could try?

Cheers